# mod_rewrite fails at string "asdf", all other tested strings work - why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Url `localhost/some_text` is rewritten to `localhost/index.php?u=some_text`. When trying many different strings, by accident I found that "asdf", meaning `localhost/asdf` **redirects** to the default apache page (I am using XAMPP, so xampp home folder).

Has anybody an idea why?? Is there sth wrong with anything in `.htaccess`? Or would you too consider this a strange behaviour?

PS: there is no directory named `asdf` nor any file or extension `asdf` in this folder nor anywhere...

Comment: i've tested, but it's working quite fine! check out ur `index.php` file